# How to set length of page title for a particular library

Tags: 2013, page-layout, publishing-page

I have a site in which there is `Pages` library. In this library there is `Title` field. I want to restrict this field to 50 chars. Default length is 255.

I tried to change it by going into `List settings` of this library, then I clicked on `Title` field but there is no option to define length.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Title column is special. Aside from changing the Display Name there's not much you can do with it. While the Title field isn't used as the database key for the row, it is a logical key when thinking of an item.

You may not be able to limit the default Title column value length because the field is built in field and cannot be customized.

> I'm not sure if you can do that with the Title field in the definition
>   but inside a FeatureReceiver you could try something like this:
>
> ```
> public override void FeatureActivated(SPFeatureReceiverProperties props)
> {
>     SPWeb site = props.Feature.Parent as SPWeb;
>     SPList list = site.Lists["yourlistname"];
>     SPField titleField = list.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName("Title");
>     titleField.DisplaySize = 45;
>     titleField.Update();
>
> }
> ```

[Source](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/54d3acb5-cf97-4187-882f-3791401e1078/limiting-the-title-column-length-in-a-list)

Or Something like below in the locale

```
 SPFieldText abc =(SPFieldText ) Spcontext.Current.Site.RootWeb.Lists["abd"].Fields["Title"];

 abc.MaxLength = 20;
```

Answer (score 2):

Go to List Settings -> Validation Settings and try the following formula:

```
=LEN([Title])<50
```

You should also add a suitable error message to advise users what is wrong in the event they type too many characters.

Comment: I have tried this but it shows a very "unfriendly" error message. User doesn't even know what happened.

Comment: Yep - that is why I said you need to set a suitable message - there is an area for the message just below the formula you added